# Solidity TypeError: artifacts is not a function

Tags: typeerror

I am a student learning to write smart contracts using solidity.  When running these codes using truffle(ganache):

Helloworld.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.5.12;

contract Helloworld {
    string message = "Hello World";

    function getMessage() public view returns (string memory)  {
        return message;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public payable {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

Helloworld_migration.js

```js
const Helloworld = artifacts.require("Helloworld");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts){
  deployer.deploy(Helloworld).then(function(instance){
      instance.setMessage("Hello Again!", {value: 1000000, from: accounts[0]}).then(function(){
        console.log("Success");
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("error: " + err);
      });
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Deploy failed " + err);
  });
};
```

Helloworldtest.js

```js
const Helloworld = artifacts().require("Helloworld");

contract("Helloworld", async function(){
  it("should initialize correctly", async function(){
    let instance = await Helloworld.deployed();
    let message = await instance.getMessage();
    assert(message === "Hello Again!");
  });
});
```

I received this error msg:

```
TypeError: artifacts is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cherrybluemoon/projects/test/Helloworldtest.js:1:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1123:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
    at Mocha.run 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:536:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle- 
    core/lib/test.js:135:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove "()" from artifacts.
`const Helloworld = artifacts.require("Helloworld");`

Answer (score 0):

`Helloworld_migration.js` is an invalid file name for a migration file. It needs to start with a number such as `1_migration.js` or `1_helloworld_migration.js`